# How do I search YouTube from my app in android

Tags: android, search, youtube

I would like to give my user the ability to search for a video on youtube from my app.

How is that possible?

Do I need to start an http session with YouTube and query it?
or maybe there is a complete package that does it all?

What about the YouTube APIs and Tools that google provieds, can I use it also on android?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + "Search text "));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Easest way to search in youtube .

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any web API when you get to it's core, is going to be some form of a webservice which all the major mobile platforms support.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api

The most complicated part you'll have to deal with is learning how to support OAuth 2.0 in your application. While version 2.0 is somewhat easier than 1.0 expect this to be the biggest hurdle to accessing the YouTube API. The good news is that a lot of other web APIs use OAuth 2.0 so try to make your classes as modular as possible so you can re-use them when you decide to start accessing Facebook, Twitter, Dropbox and a number of other well known services.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication.html#Authentication

Comment: So basically I can use in android anything I can use in java?

Comment: Not everything. Most of the standard libraries are available but there are definite Android specific classes that must be used in certain cases.